# exists ( ) function not working as expected

Tags: apache-age

I used `exists()` function to check if a given vertex is present in graph. It should have returned true but it is giving a error.

```
  SELECT * FROM cypher ('test', $$
  MATCH (n {val: 13})
  RETURN EXISTS(n)
  $$) AS (res agtype);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Apache AGE, to pass a vertex as an argument to the `EXISTS()` function, you need to enclose it within parentheses. Here's an example of the updated syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('test', $$
        MATCH (n {val: 13})
        RETURN exists((n))
    $$) AS (res agtype);
```

In this query, `(n)` is passed as an argument to `EXISTS()` to check for the existence of the vertex.

Alternatively, if you want to achieve the same result pass the `n.val` property as the argument to `EXISTS()`, you can modify the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher ('test', $$
    MATCH (n {val: 13})
    RETURN exists(n.val)
$$) AS (res agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used it correctly. It's used for different purposes and its correct syntax is as follows:

This example is for the exists(property)

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
     MATCH (n)
     WHERE exists(n.surname)
     RETURN n.first_name, n.last_name
$$) as (first_name agtype, last_name agtype);
```

If you are using property then you can write directly, else you have to write that in the brackets.

Now, if we want to check the existence of path

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
     MATCH (n)
     WHERE exists((n)-[]-({name: 'Willem Defoe'}))
     RETURN n.full_name
$$) as (full_name agtype);
```

Now, you can clearly see the difference and hope you will understand from it. For more, you can check that documentation.

[Exist keyword Documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html#exists-path)

Answer (score 0):

Exist function returns true if a certain property exists in a node, relationship, or map. This is different from exists clause. It returns an agtype boolean.

Here is a sample example of how the exist works:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
     MATCH (n)
     WHERE exists(n.surname)
     RETURN n.first_name, n.last_name
```

$$) as (first_name agtype, last_name agtype);

The above query returns the first name and last name of the people whose surname property exists in the graph.

If you want to check if a given vertex is present in the graph you can do this by using the below query:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.val = 13
RETURN EXISTS(n) AS exists
```

The query will first match all the nodes in the graph then it will filter the nodes based on property val = 13. The last line of the query will return a boolean value that will indicate whether the property exists in the graph or not.

I hope it helps, you can read more on [exists](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html#exists-property), documentation on apache age, and [Apache age's](https://github.com/apache/age) Github.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `exists()` function is to be used with a `WHERE` clause.

Secondly, the property or relationship you are checking for should be in parentheses i.e `exists((property))`.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` is used to check if a property or relationship exists on a node, but it cannot be used directly to check the existence of a node itself.

[Documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html#exists-path)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error lies in the fact that EXISTS() functions only take a single vertex as the argument whereas the query you are using makes use of the MATCH() clause. The MATCH() clause basically returns a list of vertices. Now for the next step, the EXISTS() function will return true only in case the list of vertices is not empty, while on the other hand, the list of vertices will be empty in your case. Hence, the function is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation,
exists(property) returns true if the specified property exists in the node, relationship or map.

The syntax for this is: exists(property)

The query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH (n)
    WHERE exists(n.surname)
    RETURN n.first_name, n.last_name
$$) as (first_name agtype, last_name agtype);
```

You can also refer to the documentation: [Exists()](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html#exists-property)

Answer (score 0):

The `EXISTS()` function is a predicate function which returns a boolean (True or False) depending on if a specified property exists in a node, and it is used along with the `WHERE` clause, so your updated query would be;

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
MATCH (n {val: 13})
WHERE EXISTS(n.val)
RETURN n
$$) AS (res agtype);
```

You can get more insight on the `EXISTS()` function by reading the [AGE DOCS- EXISTS](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/functions/predicate_functions.html#exists-path)

Answer (score 0):

The way your query's **EXISTS()** function operates is the cause of the issue you're experiencing. The **MATCH()** clause in your query produces a list of vertices even though this function requires a single vertex as its argument.

To be clear, the **MATCH()** clause returns an empty list if there are no matching vertices but gets all vertices that satisfy the stated criteria. If the list of vertices is not empty, the **EXISTS()** method returns true; otherwise, it returns false.

In your case, the **MATCH()** clause returned an empty list since it was unable to locate any vertices with the value *"val: 13"*. As a result, the **EXISTS()** function returns false since it is determining whether the list has any vertices.